# Concat using for each loop and and keyword

Tags: xslt-1.0

Recently I've encountered a case where in i should apply a for each loop and concat strings using 'and' keyword. Below is a part of my xml document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<case.ref.no.group>
    <case.ref.no>
        <prefix>Civil Appeal</prefix>
        <number>W-02-887</number>
        <year>2008</year>
    </case.ref.no>
    <case.ref.no>
        <prefix>Civil Appeal</prefix>
        <number>W-02-888</number>
        <year>2008</year>
    </case.ref.no>
</case.ref.no.group>
```

and i tried the below xslt on it.

```
<xsl:template match="case.ref.no.group">
    <xsl:variable name="pre">
      <section class="sect2">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">Court of Appeal</xsl:text>
      </section>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="tex">
      <xsl:value-of select="./case.ref.no/prefix"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="iter">

        <xsl:value-of select="./case.ref.no/number"/>
        <xsl:if test="following::case.ref.no/number">;</xsl:if>

    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="year">
      <xsl:value-of select="./case.ref.no/year"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <div class="para">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($pre,' – ',$tex,' Nos. ',$iter,'-',$year)"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

when i try to run it it is giving me the below output.

**Court of Appeal – Civil Appeal Nos. W-02-887 2008**

but i want it to be as below.

**Court of Appeal – Civil Appeal Nos. W-02-887-2008 and W-02-888-2008**

please let me know how i can achieve this. i'm doing this in xslt 1.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand well what exactly you are trying to do. You mentioned `for-each` but in your code is not present, you mentioned word `and` and you don't use it :-)

If I use following stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="case.ref.no.group" />
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="case.ref.no.group">
        <section class="sect2">
            <xsl:text>Court of Appeal</xsl:text>
        </section>

        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="case.ref.no[1]/prefix" />
        <xsl:text> Nos. </xsl:text> 

        <xsl:for-each select="case.ref.no">
            <xsl:value-of select="number" />
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="year" />
            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"><section class="sect2">Court of Appeal</section> - Civil Appeal Nos. W-02-887-2008 and W-02-888-2008</output>
```

But as I said I'm not sure if I understand your needs well. For example I'm not sure if you don't need some kind of grouping (prefix will be everytime same in all `<case.ref.no>` under one parent `<case.ref.no.group>`?) etc.